# Shaderlab and Cg API reference

Tags: unity, shaders, cg, shaderlab

I am looking for definitive information on Shaderlab's API and the Cg language. The documentation I have found so far has been by way of example programs rather than a definition of APIs. Also, searching for a specific API term such as Sampler2D didn't turn up anything definitive.

What reference documentation is available or possibly documentation of precursors to Shaderlab and Cg?

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackExchange! This Q&A site is best for solving specific problems that you've encountered in game development, but it's not the best place to learn how to get started, or to poll about personal experiences. For finding [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Shader.html) and [tutorials, a simple search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=unity+shader+tutorial) will get you more answers, faster. To chat about dev experiences, consider using a discussion forum like GameDev.net. Once you've started on your shader and hit a particular snag, ask here to get specific help.

Comment: I've reworded the question and hopefully it's more suitable now.

Comment: This is still a question about documentation, which as I pointed out before, can be answered with a simple search. For example, [searching Sampler 2D CG leads to this CG documentation from NVIDIA](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter03.html) (See section 3.2.1 "Sampler Objects"), and the ShaderLab docs are linked in my comment above. If after reading the documentation you still have a specific question you're unsure how to answer, please do ask that here.